# Cargar combobox con registros disponibles

Tags: mysql, sql

Hola gente del grupo tengo una aplicación de escritorio hecha en c# y Windws Forms.
Es una aplicación para gestionar los turnos de una clínica.
Tengo que cargar un combobox Solo con los horarios que están disponibles.
Lo que no se como hacer es para saber en la tabla de Turnos que horarios tengo disponibles. La base de datos la tengo en MySql.
Está es la estructura de mis dos tablas. Turnos y Horarios

```
Turnos
Turnos_ID int auto_increment,
Turnos_IDPaciente int,
Turnos_Fecha date,
Turnos_IDHorarios int,
primary key (Turnos_ID)

Horarios
Horarios_ID int auto_increment,
Horario_Horario time,
primary key (Horarios_ID)
```

[image: Tabla Turnos]
[image: Tabla Horarios]
[image: Consulta]

```
select
Turnos_ID,
Pacientes_Nombre,
Pacientes_TelefonoUno,
Turnos_IDHorarios,
Horario_Horario,
Turnos_Fecha
from Pacientes, Turnos, Horarios
where Turnos_IDPaciente = Pacientes_ID
and Turnos_IDHorarios = Horarios_ID
and Turnos_Fecha = '2021-11-24'
order by Horarios_ID;
```

Comment: Probaste algo? seria todo lo que este en horarios que no este en turnos, no?

Comment: Trate de hacer un tabla auxiliar pero no supe como armarla. Lo único que necesito es resolver el problema en la base de datos después no tengo problema para cargar los datos al combobox.
Exactamente ese es el problema. Me podrías dar una sugerencia de como armar una tabla auxiliar o alguna consulta sql que me ayude.

Comment: porque una tabla auxiliar?? que datos tienen esas tablas?

Comment: La tabla turnos tiene todos los turnos de la clínica. Tiene 2 claves foráneas. Una para enlazar con la tabla de pacientes y la otra con los horarios. La tabla horarios solamente tiene el ID del turno y el horario (por ejemplo 08:00 hs)
Había pensado en una tabla auxiliar pero estoy re perdido.
Necesito saber que turnos están disponibles en la tabla turnos para que esos turnos no se carguen el el combobox. Subí imágenes de las tablas.

Comment: Tu codigo, siempre como texto, si no, es dificil copiar y pegar para ayudarte...

Comment: Las agregue porque pensé que podían ayudar a entender. No sabes si habrá alguna forma de recorrer  la tabla turnos y saber que turnos están disponibles?

Comment: Estaba perfecto lo que agregaste, pero el codigo de tu query, debe ir como texto!.. y no tenes que recorrer nada, te alcanza con usar un not in en el where....

Comment: Ahí agregue la consulta en modo de código. Como sería la query para saber que turnos están disponibles.

Comment: Selecciona toda la tabla horarios.. y usa not in, contra el dia que queres ver los horarios libres ;)...

Comment: No entendí bien tu respuesta porque en la tabla turnos no tengo la fecha, la fecha la tengo en la tabla turnos.

Comment: Amigo me funciono perfecto la consulta. No tuve problemas para cargar el combobox. Te agradezco tu ayuda! No te doy puntos porque no me dejan poner puntos acá en este foro, porque soy muy nuevo. Lo que no se es si habrá alguna forma de marcarla como respuesta como en otros foros.

Comment: Si podes dar puntos. si podes marcar la respuesta como aceptada. si podes comentar debajo de la respuesta y no en cualquier lado. leiste el [tour] pero se ve que no lo entendiste.. leelo de vuelta, y fijate como funciona el sitio. en tus preguntas, podes hacer lo que quieras....

Answer (score 1):

Tenes que seleccionar, para cada fecha, todos los horarios que no esten tomados...

Para eso, podes hacer algo asi:

```
select
    Horario_Horario,
    Horaios_ID
from 
    Horarios
where
    Horaios_ID not in 
    (select Turnos_IDHorarios from turnos
        where Turnos_Fecha = '2021-11-24')
```

Ese query busca los horarios, que no esten tomados en la tabla turnos, para la fecha que pongas.